# Order By Before Group By in JPA Spring Repository

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

So my aim is for a specific book (with the given id), to get the published version for each language. If there is no version that is published then I need to retrieve the most recent, by the timestamp.

I need to do a query whereby the order by is performed before group.

I know in sql you can do (roughly)

```
Select * From 
( Select b from Book as b where b.author = ?1 ORDER BY (case when b.info.status=published then 1 else 2) asc, b.timestamp desc)
GroupBy book.language
```

However I dont know how to do a similar join thorugh a query in a jpa repository using hibernate. 
I know this doesnt work, as the order is lost due to the 'in'

```
Select a From book a where a.id in  
( Select b from Book as b where b.author=?1 ORDER BY (case when b.info.status=published then 1 else 2) asc, b.timestamp desc)
GroupBy a.language
```

As it goes through and checks in, this means the order is not kept. Is there anyway to do this query in jpa repository?

I don't want to have to  do a 'for each' and get the published/latest as this will be greatly inefficient

The books is setup as

book | author| info id

Then info id has:

infoid| language| timestamp | status|.........

**An example** aim would be :
Get j.k. rowlings published/latest in each language

example setup of book would be

```
book | author | info id
1    |Rowling |1 
2    |Rowling |2
3    |Rowling |3
4    |Rowling |4
5    |Tolkein |5
```

info:

```
id|lang|ts | status
1 |en  |1  | published
2 |de  |5  | unpublished
3 |de  |3  | unpublished
4 |en  |9  | unpublished
5 |en  |4  | published
```

Requesting it woudl return book
1 (as published and in english), and 2 (as in de, with the highest timestamp out of de)

Comment: GROUP BY (2 words) ?

Comment: Are you thinking there will be more books with the same info id? Or there will be more info id with the same book? The different book records will be able to have different authors, will it be ok?

Comment: Hi Sorry for not being clear
Each book will have it's own info id.
One author will have multiple books.  There are multiple authors, however I will be concerned with one in particular. 

Therefore the aim is to fetch the published, otherwise latest, for each language of each book, for a specific author.  Think of books as more revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not ok. SQL doesn't work with ordered sets, SQL is working (mainly) with unordered sets. That means, that every query, query result, subquery and such are an unordered set of records.

Yes, this is because these sets are theoretically exactly the sets which you could learn from in high school.

If you do a `GROUP BY`, a `JOIN`, or any similar, a previous `ORDER BY` will be invalidated. Why? Because every such keyword is working with unordered sets. This is also the cause, why only the last SQL query can have an `ORDER BY`.

If somehow this internal ordering works, it is only a randomly behaviour of some SQL servers (old MySQL versions were especially curious in such solutions).

What you wanted, is

1. GROUP-in the records by *two* columns (`published` and `language`)
2. *ORDERING* the needed records by this two columns as well.

So:

`SELECT b
FROM Book b
WHERE author=?1 AND info.status=published
ORDER BY published, language`

...or such. If I could decipher what do you want, probably even a `group by` were unneeded. If you extend your question, what is your goal, I will extend my answer with the query.

*Extension #1:*

It can't be done with basic SQL, which it requires *windowing functions*. An SQL query which does what you want:

`SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ts PARTITION BY author, lang ORDER BY ts) AS tsn
FROM Book b
LEFT JOIN info i ON b.info_id=i.id
WHERE tsn=1`

Anyways, you should look for the `ROW_NUMBER()` SQL function, and probably you won't need `GROUP BY`.

I furhter don't have any clue how could it be ported to hql (hibernate query language), but I will do a little bit of research around this soon.

*Extension #2:*

Mysql doesn't have windowing function or anything which made SQL useful. In ancient times it was because they had not enough programmer and wanted a fast system, not a smart. Currently, it is because MySQL is owned by Oracle and they want a free concurrent to their SQL server. Anyways, MySQL is bad, and on longterm, especially if you are enough good for Java, I suggest you use some better DB (with PostgreSQL you were really satisfied, I think).

Until then, here is an SQL solution. It is a little bit complex. First, we get the maximal timestamp for every author, book and language:

`SELECT book.author, book.id as book_id, info.lang, MAX(info.ts) AS ts
FROM book
LEFT JOIN info ON book.info_id=info.id
GROUP BY book.author, book.id, info.lang`

We call this query as `$queryMaxts`. Try this query, it should work.

After that, we can join this back to the tables we wish:

`SELECT *
FROM ($queryMaxts) maxts
LEFT JOIN book ON maxts.author=book.author
LEFT JOIN info ON maxts.lang=info.lang AND maxts.ts=info.ts AND book.info_id=info.id`

...although it is a pure MySQL solution and has nothing to the JPA to do. I suggest embedding this into the JPA layer somehow.

*Another important thing:*

You are nearly sure that the timestamps are unique. You can guarantee that which made you database faster too, by creating a unique index: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqts ON info(lang, ts)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my answer with additional information.
Looking at your post It may work by, grouping by published AND language, sorted by language
This will greatly reduce the number, where it may be feasable in java to loop through and just keep track if a language is already used.

Comment: The issue With what I suggested of grouping on published and language, is that grouping means that if two are unpublished, then the first one will be taken, even if the second has a greater timestamp. This is the issue forementioned of needing to order before grouping

Comment: @user1628284 No, it is totally bad. If you GROUP by a field, you can SELECT only the GROUP-ed field or aggregated functions (f.e. "MAX()") from any other columns. Only Mysql doesn't follow that, because they don't want make harder the life for basic SQL beginners, but it is a damaged thing even there. I give you a working solution soon.

Comment: @user1628284 Finally I understood your problem! That is very interesting, and it can't be done with simple group & order things! (Or only very problematic). Which SQL do you use? With hibernate it is also very hard. In your place I tried to use some tricky SQL view.

Comment: Thanks for your help .
It is on a mysql server, however I am using JPQL to write the query, in a spring repository using hibernate.  I may make it very inefficient and just retrieve all languages, then loop through one by one. I spent a day and have not had much success.

Comment: @user1628284 Ok, mysql is primitive, it doesn't have windowing functions or practically nothing which made sql useful. My ROW_NUMBER() solution won't work. My second idea were (after your sql server change to, f.e., postgresql) a little bit tricky solution based on GROUP-ing and JOIN-ing. Can you guarantee that your timestamps will be unique for a given book? What is their precision?

Comment: The Timestamps should be unique. They are down to the second, and one can only be created after another. However there may be 1 in a million chance that theyy are not uniique, if say a bug means they are set incorrectly.

Comment: @user1628284 Okay, next iteration done. If you are satisfied with an answer, you can accept that by clicking the green pipe icon on the left side. It is a reward to the answerer.